# AWS RDS: Is there a way to determine if a db instance was turned on automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

AWS will automatically turn on db instances that have been dormant for 7 days, and I can programmatically turn off a db instance. So is there any way to determine if the db instance was turned on automatically so I can turn it back off again? I certainly don't want to turn off the instance if an actual person has turned it on.